# If both $x+10$ and $x-79$ are perfect squares, what is $x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If both $x+10$ and $x-79$ are perfect squares, what is $x$?

That is:

$x+10=$perfect square  (or can be square such that the result of it squared is a positive integer)

$x-79=$perfect square  (or can be square such that the result of it squared is a positive integer)

I have no idea how to solve this.I tried inequality like

$$x+10>x-79$$
$$x-x>-79-10$$
$$0>-89$$

Note: You are not allowed to use trial and error or guess and check to solve the question.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please try to phrase it so someone can tell what it is you're asking exactly. Also, you should show what work you have done to try to answer the question.

Comment: In light of the answer ($x=2015$), it seems as if "You are not allowed to use trial and error..." is gratuitous.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way, again assuming that $x$ must be an integer: We have
$$
a^2 = x+10,\qquad b^2=x-79
$$
so $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)=89$ and, since we're in the integers and 89 is prime, we have
$$
a+b=89, \qquad a-b = 1
$$
from which it follows that $a=45, b=44$. Thus
$$
a^2=45^2=2025=x+10
$$
so $x=2015$, which puts it squarely (ahem) in the region of PuzzleLand where the answers are part of the current date.

Comment: PERFECT ANSWER NEED THANK YOU :D

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are looking for positive integers...

Consecutive squares differ by consecutive odd amounts. The first differences to $\{0,1,4,9,16,\ldots\}$ are $\{1,3,5,7,\ldots\}$.

You have two squares that are $89$ apart. They may or may not be consecutive. But for some string of consecutive odd numbers, the sum must be $89$.

$$
\begin{align}
(2k+1)+\left(2(k+1)+1\right)\cdots+\left(2(k+h)+1\right)&=89\\
2k(h+1)+h(h+1)+h+1&=89\\
(2k+h+1)(h+1)&=89\\
\end{align}$$
Since $89$ is prime, either $h=0$ and $k=44$, or well, there is no other possibility.

So $k=44$ and there is only one consecutive odd number in our sequence, meaning the two squares must be consecutive squares. We must be dealing with the difference between $44^2$ and $45^2$. So $x=45^2-10$.

Answer (score 0):

It is helpful to keep in mind that the difference between consecutive perfect square numbers gives us an arithmetic sequence. $$\left\{n^2\right\}_{n=1} ^{\infty},\space \space \space a_n = n^2  $$ $$a_{n+1}-a_n =(n+1)^2-n^2= 2n+1$$ Therefore, we have $x+10$ and $x-79$ as consecutive perfect square numbers. Assume that $a_{n+1}=x+10$, $a_n = x-79$. $$\begin{align} \ a_{n+1}-a_n & = 2n+1 \\
& = \ (x+10)-(x-79) \\
& = \ 89 \\ \end {align}$$ $$n=44 \space \Rightarrow \space \begin{align}
\ a_{45} & =\ 45^2 \\ 
& =\ 2025 \\ 
& =\ x+10 \\ \end{align}$$ $$x=2015$$